# stdClass obj array .. how to print individual items?

Tags: php, oop

```
Array
(
    [total_results] => 47023
    [products] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [binds] => 1627836:3269460;1627836:3269461;1627836:3269458;1627839:3269490;1627841:3269526
                            [cid] => 50010368
                            [name] => 三九光学雷朋太阳镜RayBan超轻树脂镜片运动墨镜RB4039 816/13
                            [pic_url] => //img06.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i6/TB1532SOVXXXXcJXXXXN951FFXX_093838.jpg
                            [price] => 980.00
                            [product_id] => 717498724
                            [props] => 20000:55652;1629764:3596338
                            [status] => 0
                            [tsc] => CIKCQQU
                        )
```

I didn't code long time ago and trying to print this array using for each loop.

Can anyone help please in printing the array items such as the 'price' for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's just looping over an object and an array:

```
foreach ($array['products']->product as $product) {
  echo $product->price;
}
```

Comment: Assuming your variable above is called $array